# How to remove the embedded formatting of an UTF-8 string?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, utf-8, facebook-php-sdk

I'm querying the Facebook API in PHP to get a list of posts and display it on a website.

```php
// $facebook is an instance of Facebook\Facebook
$response = $facebook->get('posts?fields=id,message,created_time,full_picture,permalink_url,status_type&limit=20');
$graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
$posts = [];

foreach ($graphEdge as $post) {
    $message = $post->getField('message');
}
```

The text returned by the call looks like the picture below:

[image]

My problem is that sometimes the formatting of the text seems to be embedded in the characters themselves. For eg., the text "Montélimar - aux Portes du Soleil" uses a different font than what's defined in CSS and I can't force it to use a different style. The HTML looks like this:

```html
<p>
  Profitez d’un cadre de vie idéal pour faire construire votre maison individuelle sur la commune de ́ -     ☀️
  Notre lotissement «    ́ » ...
</p>
```

We even store the data in a JSON object and it looks like this (see the "description" field):

```json
[
    {
        "pageName": "---",
        "type": "---",
        "date": "---",
        "description": "Profitez d’un cadre de vie idéal pour faire construire votre maison individuelle sur la commune de ́ -     ☀️ Notre lotissement «    ́ » ...",
        "time": 0000,
        "thumbnail": "---",
        "url": "---",
        "img": "---"
    }
]
```

As you can see, some text has a default styling that I can't figure how to get rid of. I've tried to re-encode the text to UTF-8 via PHP using `mb_convert_encoding();` but this doesn't solve the problem because the string is already UTF-8.

**How can I remove this formatting? Is this even formatting, or just special UTF-8 symbols?**

Answer (score 1):

If you copy one of the characters (the "M" of "Montélimar" for eg.) and try to look for it in the Unicode Character Table (https://unicode-table.com/en/1D40C/), you will find that it is not a letter but a "Mathematical Bold Capital M", represented by these symbols:

- Unicode number: `U+1D40C`
- HTML-code: `&#119820;`

So this is a problem with your content itself and not an encoding problem. Everything is fine and I don't think you can anything do to fix this appearance issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the UTF-8 special characters get in the way, you can try converting the string to ASCII with [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php). However, there is a risk that the individual characters and, under certain circumstances, important information will be lost.

```
$strUTF8mb4 = "Profitez d’un cadre de vie idéal pour faire construire votre maison individuelle sur la commune de ́ -     ☀️ Notre lotissement «    ́ » ...";
$strASCII = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $strUTF8mb4);
//string(181) "Profitez d'un cadre de vie id'eal pour faire construire votre maison individuelle sur la commune de Montelimar - aux Portes du Soleil Notre lotissement << Le Domaine de Gery >> ..."
```

Especially for the French language, this code could produce slightly better results:

```
$strIso = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $strUTF8mb4);
$strUtf8 = iconv("ISO-8859-15", "UTF-8", $strIso);
//"Profitez d'un cadre de vie idéal pour faire construire votre maison individuelle sur la commune de Montelimar - aux Portes du Soleil Notre lotissement « Le Domaine de Gery » ..."
```

Comment: that's a nice solution, however, I think that losing the emojis is not acceptable. But I'll keep it in mind nonetheless.

Comment: If you happen to have an idea to convert the UTF-8 chars whilst keeping the emojis I would be interested!

Comment: To do this, the string would have to be split into emojis and other UTF8 characters. Finding an emoji in a string is what supposed to do the PHP class  emoji-detector-php : https://github.com/aaronpk/emoji-detector-php.